# Spark-SQL Query Hints for Join Performance Improvement

Tags: apache-spark-sql, query-hints

I have recently been introduced to `SparkSQL`. We use `Spark 2.4`. I recently found out that `SparkSQL` query supports the following hints for its Join strategies:

- BROADCAST hint
- MERGE hint
- SHUFFLE_HASH hint

Unfortunately, I have not found any online materials which elaborately discuss these hints and their application scenarios. I wish to learn some tips regarding when to use these hints in a query Join for improving query performance.

Can anyone explain with some examples.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Broadcast join is very high performance join with sending data of the small table to every executor to execute a map-side join . here is the configuration :spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold
2. Sort-merge join is a default join choice after spark 2.3

there are some post ,Hope it help you: 
[Spark SQL Joins](https://medium.com/datakaresolutions/optimize-spark-sql-joins-c81b4e3ed7da)
[Sort-Merge Join](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/sort-merge-join-spark-sql/read)